# Javascript method to find intersection point of two lines given three points and slopes

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, line-intersection

I searched for this and found similar answers but they were more math based than programming based, and I need a little help putting it in to code.

I have an arbitrary shape, but let's call it a diamond for now, with the following coordinates:

A = (0,0)

B = (50, 50)

C = (0, 100)

D = (-50, 50)

Think of the movement contraints on this as if you had a rubber band and moved a peg.  The lines will always connect but their orientation to one another must not change.  So since the slope of AB is 1, it needs to remain 1.  I have that part working fine.

Now, say I move "B" such that it rests at (100, 100).  I know the slopes of AB (unchanged), BC (before B was moved, and after, but after is useless and wrong), CD (unchanged) and DA (unchanged).  I also know the coordinates of A, B and D.  I need to find the position of C, such that all slopes remain unchanged and it rests at the logical point where BC and CD should intersect.

Mathematically, I know C belongs at (50, 150) now but I need a generalized formula to figure this out.  This is a single example so what I'm looking for is something generalized enough to reuse.  Of course, there are snags when lines are parallel or vertical but I can handle that.

This picture should help visualize it.  B started at "B" and I moved it to "B2".  C needs to move to ???

Thanks a ton if you can help!

[image: Line constraints]

EDIT:  This seems to be the answer, but I'm anything but a math whiz and don't get how it translates in to some sort of generalized formula.  [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect?rq=1)

Comment: I am not really understanding how you want this described without using math? It's a mathematical concept and even one that translates fairly simply into code. I'm not trying to be rude, just confused.

Comment: No no, of course it's math.  I mean I found the algebraeic/geometric way to do it.  I'm just having trouble putting it in to some generalized code.

Comment: Write out the steps you go through to solve the problem in math, create a function in JS that simulates it, and use IF/ELSE statements to give the code the logic necessary, i.e. which points it needs to recalculate.

Comment: When you move `B` to `B2` it's `x` and `y` coordinates increased by, say `sx` and `sy`. I suppose you only want to increrase the coordinates of `B2` by exact same numbers, right?

Comment: @neo - you're right, but it needs to be more generic than that.  Just taking the difference between B2 and B and applying that difference to C to find C2 would work, but not if the angles are more arbitrary.

Comment: I think you need to add more explanaition. (or even better: more examples)

Comment: @oooyaya Why shouldn't that work? If B2 is moved 100 units up and 50 units right, C2 is 100 units up from C and 50 units right from C.

Comment: OK - I must not have communicated my problem very well.  I'll reexplain but it will have to wait.  Sorry to waste your time :(

Comment: @oooyaya Sorry, I didn't realize B was **moved to** B2. I thought another, new point was put down at B2